# jfreechart remove horizontal dotted line

Tags: java, jfreechart, graphic

I am getting a lot of problems with jfreechart.

I want to draw a graphic (StackedBarChartGraphic with a DefaultCategoryDataset for input).

I want a graphic like this: [image: desired graph]

The problem goes when I get the graphic like this: [image: error graph]

I want to remove those horizontal dotted lines at 100, 200, 300 and so on and (also) put a black line at value 0 (i.e. draw the 0 axis as a black line). I tried this:

```
CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.gray);
plot.setDomainGridlinesVisible(false);
plot.clearRangeMarkers();
plot.clearAnnotations();
```

And doesn't work. Any ideas? Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you tried `setDomainGridlinesVisible(false)`? Have you tried a `Marker` or `Annotation`? Please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your current approach.

Comment: Yeah trashgod, that worked!!!! Thank you very much!

Comment: Excellent; you can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188) to clarify what worked.